# A difficulty in understanding the finite intersection property.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, compactness

I am supposed to solve this question:

[image]

1-But I have a difficulty in understanding the finite intersection property mentioned in it. could anyone explain this property for me by a concrete example?

2- Also how this leads leads that $A$ is a compact set, any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complements of the sets in $\cal F$ are open, and the condition that
$$\bigcap_{F\in\cal F}(F\cap A)=\emptyset\tag{1}$$
means that
$$\bigcup_{U\in\cal U}(U\cap A)=A\tag{2}$$
where ${\cal U}=\{F^c:F\in\cal F\}$ is the collection of complements of
the sets in $\cal F$. The condition $(1)$ is then
equivalent to $U\cap A$ are an open cover of $A$.

Compactness means that $(2)$ holding means that it still holds when
we replace $\cal U$ by some finite subset. In that case we can replace
$\cal F$ in $(1)$ by a finite subset, and that is the finite intersection
property.

Comment: does not (2) is the complement of (1)? if so how A and the intersection inside remains the same?

Comment: I mean the inside intersection and the A on the left hand side in (2) should be the empty set?

Comment: @hopefully I think these are right.....

Comment: yeah I understood your idea now ...... but to prove from compactness the finite intersection property is it using the same argument above?

Comment: @hopefully Yes, it's the same argument  in reverse.

Comment: but how can I write the proof starting by assuming that $A$ has an arbitrary open cover? the sequence of the proof is not clear for me?